# Javascript: Execute function with different execution context

Tags: javascript, function, scope, executioncontext

Is there a way to change the execution context of a Javascript function manually at execution time?

I am **not** talking about changing the `this` reference to point to a different object - I know this can be done with `Function.prototype.call()/apply()`.

I am talking about changing variables accessible to the function, or to be more specific, granting access to variables that are outside of the scope the function is defined in.

Example:

```
var func;
(function () {
    func = function () {
        alert(test); // no variable called "test" defined, it will
                     // result in a ReferenceError when func() is called
    }
})();


function callFunction (callee) {
    var test ='foobar';
    callee(); // callee does not have access to "test"
}

callFunction(func);
```

In this example, I'd love the function `func` to be able to access the variable `test` defined in `callFunciton` when it is called. However due to how scope and execution contexts work in Javascript, it doesn't work that way.

I am looking for a way for `callFunction` to insert a variable called `test` in the execution context of the `callee()` call.

---

In this minimal example, it is of course possible to just add test as a parameter to func().

My use-case however is a framework with a plugin infrastructure, where plugins can specify callbacks and what parameters they take - along with parameter types. The framework then takes care of converting requested data into the requested types and provide them to the callback. This should happen completely transparent to the plugin.

Pseudocode:

*Plugin*

```
function callback {
    alert(user.name);
    alert(number);
};
var callbackParams = [
    {name : 'user', type : User},
    {name : 'number', type : Number}
];
defineCallback('event', callback, callbackParams);
```

*Framework*

```
var on = {
    event : [];
}

var User = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function defineCallback (event, callback, params) {
    on[event].push({
        callback : callback;
        params   : params;
    });
}

function handleEvent(event) {
    on[event].forEach(function (handler) {
        for (param of handler.params) {
            // 1) gather data
            // 2) create Object of correct type as specified in 
            //    param.type
            // 3) insert variable called param.name into 
            //    execution context of handler.callback
        }
        handler.callback();
    });
}
```

So far, I found three solutions to this problem, and I like neither:

- define parameters in callback, and only define their types in callbackParams, indexed by their order in the function declaration. Disadvantage: parameters have to be declared in two places.
- use `this.paramname` instead of just `paramname` in callback, and use `.call()/.apply()` in `handleEvent(). Disadvantage: not transparent to plugins.
- assign the variables to global scope before calling `handler.callback()` in `handleEvent()` and delete them again afterwards. Disadvantage: very ugly workaround.

Ideas?

Comment: Short answer, **no**, functions don't have access to variables unless they are in scope, so either you pass the variables as arguments or you make them available to the scope of the function, or a higher scope, which should be doable if you don't wrap everything in IIFE's

Comment: you have to re-eval() the function code to re-assess closures.

Comment: My "idea" is that you reconsider your design. It's simply wrong. It's counter intuitive, it's unnatural to the language (and probably to any language), it's untestable (for the plugin developer), and worst of all, the simple solution (explicitly declared arguments) has everything you need without any real downside.

Comment: @adeneo The wrapping in the IIFE in the minimal example was intentional, as it reporduces the use-case where the function is defined in a plugin but called in the framework

Comment: @dandavis That is actually more ugly then using global scope as a workaround... it IS certainly an option though, yes.

Comment: @Amit It's most likely what I will do.

Comment: Thank god **no**. [Dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) is the horror. That's what parameters and argument passing is made for.

Comment: For your use case, you should use `function callback(user, number) { … }` and just pass the values in the order in which they are given in the `callbackParams`. You might even drop the `name` and just specify the `type` if you don't need them otherwise.

Comment: @Bergi that is basically what I thought about in the first of my 3 possible workarounds - and certainly the one I like the most. I'm just not comfortable with specifying parameters in two different places (function declaration and the `callbackParams` array), but it does seem like the cleanest solution. Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: @Amit: Actually there are languages that had this "feature". They died out relatively quickly, were/are used only in small projects, or required ferocious style rules to stay maintainable.

Comment: @JohannesH.: You could visually colocate them, e.g. `callback.types = [User, Number]; ¶ function callback(user, number) { ¶ …`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `with` statement. Be aware it's slow and forbidden in strict mode.

```js
var func;
(function () {
  func = function func() {
    with(func.variables) {
      console.log(test);
    }
  }
})();
function callFunction (callee) {
  callee.variables = {test: "foobar"};
  callee();
  callee.variables = null;
}
callFunction(func);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I completely forgot about `with` as I haven't used it in years for good reason... I like the approach of assigning the variables to a property of the callback function, I didn't think about this one yet. I would have to specify the plugin infrastructure that callbacks have access to their parameters that way then - if a plugin developer uses `with` in them or not is outside of my responsibility though.

Comment: Still, `callee.variables` is just a rather crude workaround of simply passing the variable object into the function as a parameter. Whether the plugin uses `with` or not isn't even your decision then.